# How do I specify in an Ajax.Beginform accept-charset="gb2312"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add an ajax form to my application. The problem is that I want to pass my input as gb2312 encoded. However I wasn't able to do

```
new {accept-charset="gb2312"}
```

as [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504974(VS.100).aspx) suggested. I guess it's because the "-" in "accept-charset" breaks the CSharp variable naming rule. I tried to add an "@" in front of "accept-charset" but it didn't work either. Does anyone know what trick should I apply to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN is wrong: accept-charset is not a valid identifier.

Try using the BeginForm overload that takes an IDictionary htmlAttributes instead of an Object.

Example:

```
<% var attributes = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
   attributes.Add("accept-charset","gb2312");
   using (Ajax.BeginForm( "action", null, new AjaxOptions { ... }, attributes ))
   {
 %>

<% } %>
```

Comment: This is the way to do it.  I was thinking you needed to set the request header, but it's much simpler to just set the form attribute. Doh!  Hope you don't mind that I added an example.

Comment: It indeed worked, but has to be with one slight modification. 
var attributes has to be of type Dictionary<string, object> instead of Dictionary<string, string> otherwise the generated html is incorrect.

Comment: You could use a dictionary literal to get it a touch closer to the original syntax: var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object> {
 { "accept-charset", "gb2312" } };